# Fragment with a google map taking up half the page with one marker, force close

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I have a fragment which is supposed to load with a google map with one marker on the top half, and a text view on the bottom half of the screen. When I try and launch it I get this error:

```
06-26 12:34:06.398  20009-20009/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro, PID: 20009
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.LocationPage.onResume(LocationPage.java:89)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1543)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:974)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My LocationPage code is:

```
public class LocationPage extends Fragment {

    GoogleMap mMap;

    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    String lattitude;
    String longitude;
    String name;


    //Mandatory Constructor
    public LocationPage() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locationpage,container, false);
        //todo: set title to brewery name
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        name = prefs.getString("name", null);
        String hours = prefs.getString("hours", null);
        lattitude = prefs.getString("lat", null);
        longitude = prefs.getString("lng", null);
        String phone = prefs.getString("phone", null);
        getActivity().setTitle(name);
        //todo: set map
        //todo: display rest of information
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //todo: add markers
        double latD = Double.parseDouble(lattitude);
        double lngD = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latD, lngD))
                .title(name));
    }
}
```

Line 89 on LocationPage is:

```
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latD, lngD))
            .title(name));
```

My xml for LocationPage is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it means you are getting null values in onResume method for lat and lng

Comment: Just did a log in the on Resume and they are not null:

 Log.d("location" , "lat= " + lattitude);
        Log.d("location" , "lng= " + longitude);

06-26 13:32:04.300  25312-25312/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro D/location﹕ lat= 38.770622
06-26 13:32:04.300  25312-25312/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro D/location﹕ lng= -75.310893

Comment: use break point and debug your app.. surely you'll find the null Pointerexception

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have one of this variables (name, lattitude, longitude or mMap) with null value.
Try to print this variables in logcat.